# export * from "./something"; equivalent of Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have split my file containing a large number of functions into multiple files and want to have a common index.js file to export function from each file. How do I do that, using one line of code, or something similar to `export * from "./something";`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to create `index.js` file in the same dir as your functions and then export them like this

```js
export { default as FuncOne } from "./FuncOne";
export { default as FuncTwo } from "./FuncTwo";
export { default as FuncThree } from "./FuncThree";

...
```

To make sure that this works, each function will need to be exported as default in each file as per the example below.

```js
// FuncOne.js
const FunctOne = () => { ... };

export default FuncOne;
```

Answer (score -1):

no, there is not. old versions usually don't do what the new versions do, it is why they is call new versions